# SVN corrupted revision

Tags: apache-http-server, svn, repository

I am using SVN version 1.4.2. I have verified my repo and find that one revision corrupted. svnadmin verify command showing the below message. My backup also having the same issue. Please help me to resolve this issue.

> svnadmin: E200002: Serialized hash missing terminator

Answer (score 1):

It means one of the repository files is corrupt!

It could be a revision files in db/revs or it could be a revprop file in db/revprops.

```
A serialized hash is a series of K/V pairs followed by END:
```

Take a look at [this solution](http://nitinbhide.blogspot.in/2013/09/recovering-from-corrupted-subversion.html) (Python script):

- Runs the 'svnadmin verify -r ' and checks 'serialized hash missing terminator error'.
- If the error is reported, the script reads the revision properties of revision just before that (i.e. revno-1) and add One minute to the time stamp of this revision.The log message is changed 'recovered from corruption' message.
- Now original corrupted revision property file is copied to a backup location and corrected revision property is written in its place.
- The process repeats till get it 'valid revision'. At this point it stops.

Comment: Please share that Python script.